# ArcGIS Python Label Expression Error

Tags: python, arcgis

I've recently started learning Python and started using it to create label expressions in ArcMap.  I ran into an error today that I can't figure out though (and seems like it should be simple).  When I try to create the following expression:

```
def FindLabel ( [FacilityName] ):
  S = [FacilityName] 
  S = S.upper()
  return S
```

I get back an error as follows:

```
Error 0 on line 0.
Error running expression:  FindLabel(ESRIExpressionArg0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
 File "<string>", line 3, in FindLabel
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'.
```

[FacilityName] is a domained field, and Null values are allowed.  I understand, I think, that 'NoneType' means that [FacilityName] is being given a None value before it's trying to be returned, but I don't know how to fix the problem.

Thanks,

Ethan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure all the values get returned as strings, but in the case of a null value, it might be returned as `None`, which would explain the error you're getting.

You can use a `try..except` block or make a conditional statement inside your function to ignore `None` values.

Here's with `try..except`:

```
def FindLabel ( [FacilityName] ):
    try:
        S = [FacilityName] 
        S = S.upper()
        return S
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Comment: Yep, this solved the problem, thanks!  I think, when ArcMap was checking the expression, as some of the points had null values for FacilityName instead of having a string it returned the error.